# AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting with AngularJS and I have a simple repeater in a table which I display stuff. 
I don't have a controller or anything yet, I just simply initialise a JSon object with my values in my `ng-init` attribute of the `table` element. 
Inside the `table`, I un `ng-repeat` to enumerable the rows.

It doesn't seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nc5rT/

I'm new at this, and I'm following Jim Cooper's course on Pluralsight, and he does the same thing and it works. 
What did I forget?

Answer (score 2):

Your init has double quotes within double quotes.  Change the outer ones to single quotes and it works.

```
ng-init='inscriptions = [{"montant":100.0,"nom":"Guy A"},{"montant":200.0,"nom":"Guy B"},{"montant":400.0,"nom":"Guy C"}]'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nc5rT/3/

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap the ng-init content with different quotation marks than what you use within the ng-init.